Fortinet- SAML authentication for firewall policy with Virtual IP (VIP)
I need to setup a VIP on my Fortinet 101F firewall (FortiOS 7.0.16) that provides SAML authentication in my Azure environment (Azure should play the role of Identity Provider), is it possible to create such an inbound policy using the firewall I have?
